# Effect of Ajax in a function on site speed

Tags: ajax

I found out that Ajax (because of heavy script performance) can affect on site speed and reduce page load time at first.

**My question:** When I use Ajax in a function and this function calls - just- when I click a button, Can affect on site load speed or no?

For example(my example is in jquery but my question include all javascripts):

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  $("#here").load("../path/target.php");
});
```

Comment: Only when you include the jquery library external or when you have a lot of jquery your performance will reduce, so make sure you have the jquery library locally and jquery runs in your browser, so performance depends on how fast your browser is. Usually very fast!

Comment: Using AJAX happens AFTER the page has loaded, so you only need to be concerned with what the page initially loads, as per the comment above. Open your debugger, look at the Network tab and to can track what's taking long to load.